# how to get 'id' from href inside database

Tags: php, database, xampp

[Here is the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MVvq.jpg)

I have a table name issues. In that table I have a column name 'dateclose'. Every time I add a data, in that column it will automatically create a data. Here's the code:

```
 $sam = '<a href="sams.php" id='.$_POST['incidentnum'].'>Close Issue</a>';
```

'incidentnum' is like the unique key. Here's the output in the database if I added a new data:

```
incidentnum | issue | datecreate | dateclose
------------|-------|------------|----------
210         |sample | 02-12-2017 |<a href="sams.php" id=210>Close Issue</a>
```

now, I want to echo the 'dateclose' to get the id num of that certain incidentnum and change the data into

```
 date("Y-m-d")
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Inserting the html code in database is not a good practice

Comment: All I wanted to do is if I click the 'close issue' link the cell will change into the current date that's why I used the html code

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `id` you have to pass it as a query parameter.

You can do this:

```
$sam = '<a href="sams.php?id='.$_POST['incidentnum'].'">Close Issue</a>';
```

And then at the server end, can use:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Hope this helps. And make sure to handle the case where no id is passed or wrong id is passed.

Comment: All I wanted to do is if I click the 'close issue' link the cell will change into the current date that's why I used the html code

Comment: @user8230483 We never said not to use HTML. You have to use it to render the link in the browser, but storing it inside DB is not a good idea. Beside that you can use the id now and can update the closing date.

Comment: that's the only way I know to close the date

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Inserting the html code in database is not a good practice

**2nd :**  Just pass the query parameter like below .

```
<a href="sams.php?id=<?php echo $_POST['incidentnum'] ?>">Close Issue</a>
```

**3rd :**  Access it like below .

```
$incidentnum= $_GET['id'];
```

**4th :**  update query

```
 "UPDATE issue SET dateclose =CURDATE()  WHERE incidentnum='$incidentnum'";
```

**5th:** Change the html table render part . on row create set the `dateclose` column into `null` .

```
$html_table = '<table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="800" word-wrap="break-word" display="inline-block"> 
              <tr><th>Incident #</th><th>Issue</th>th>Date Closed</th></tr>'; 
foreach($result as $row){ 

    $html_table .= '<tr>
                        <td>' .$row["incidentnum"]. '</a></td>
                        <td>' .$row["issue"]. '</td> 
                        <td>';
   if(is_null($row["dateclose"])){  

      $html_table.="<a href='sams.php?id=<?php echo $row[\"incidentnum \"] ?>'>Close Issue</a>";

    }else{

       $html_table.=$row["dateclose"]; 
  }
                  $html_table. '</td>

                    </tr>';

     }
```

**5th :**  Try to use `Prepared statement or pdo` to avoid `sql injection` .

Comment: All I wanted to do is if I click the 'close issue' link the cell will change into the current date that's why I used the html code

Comment: the table? @JYoThI

Comment: yes how your rendering the  html table that part of code @user8230483

Comment: $html_table = '<table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="800" word-wrap="break-word" display="inline-block">
  <tr><th>Incident #</th><th>Issue</th>th>Date Closed</th></tr>';

  foreach($result as $row){
  
  $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$row["incidentnum"]. '</a></td><td>' .$row["issue"]. '</td>
  <td>' . $row["dateclose"]. '</td></tr>';

Comment: take a look on my updated answer . especially 5th point  last td  @user8230483

Comment: Sir, please take a look also on my updated post. I posted a pic of my table.

Comment: i understand . set the dateclose =null in database .  when fetching the data from database while use if condition like this if(is_null($row["dateclose"])){  echo"<a href='sams.php?id=<?php echo $row[\"incidentnum \"] ?>'>Close Issue</a>";  }else {  echo $row["dateclose"]  }

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is not much clear.
But I think your requirement is save close date whenever user click on `<a href="sams.php" id='.$_POST['incidentnum'].'>Close Issue</a>`

So simply you have insert CURDATE() on the database display is wherever want.

Comment: YES that's actually what I wanted to do that's why I use html code

Comment: So  you have update your code in following way: <a href="sams.php?id=<?php echo $_POST['incidentnum'] ?>">Close Issue</a> Then in sams.php you have write update query to save close date. Thats simple.

Comment: this is my query in sams.php

   $sql = "UPDATE issue SET dateclose ='$dateclose' WHERE incidentnum='$incidentnum'";

Comment: Correct query in sams.php will be as follows :$sql =  "UPDATE issue SET dateclose =CURDATE()  WHERE incidentnum='$incidentnum'";

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to get the content of id after retrieving the row from your database.

Ex :

```
$sam = '<a href="sams.php" id=213>Close Issue</a>';

preg_match('#(?<=id=).*?(?=>)#', $sam, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

Output :

```
array(1) { 
   [0] => string(3) "213" 
}
```